# Why apache throws Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat on Flask app?

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, flask, mod-wsgi

I want to setup my flask app for apache on my ubuntu server using wsgi. But after my setup, I get the following browser error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

The apache error log throws:

```
Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: 
    /var/www/html/appname/appname.wsgi
```

My wsgi file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/html/appname/")

from IdeaHound import app as application
application.secret_key = 'here_the_key'
```

and my apache config file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName server_ip_here
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/appname/appname.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/html/appname/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel info
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The **appname** folder has the following structure:
appname

```
--application.py
--appname.wsgi
--LICENSE
--README.md
--requirements.txt
--db_manage.py
--appname
----frontend
----__inity__.py
----__init__.pyc
----models
----__pycache__
----socket_interface
--AppName
----__init__.py
----static
----templates
--instance
----config.py
```

What am I missing here to make the webserver run correctly with Flask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the following link of Digital Ocean. Do as describe in it. And your app will be up and running in just 5 mins.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps

Also do check the apache error logs for more information if it still throws an error.

```
/var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Comment: the error log says WSGI script not found or unable to stat. any ideas how to resolve that?